# Why use memset in this case

Tags: c

I have inherited some code from a previous developer that has retired. My question is specifically the use of memset in the following scenario. Not being a c programmer, I am wondering why memset was used in this particular case, where the next line of code stores the value in the variable that was just set to all 0 by memset. Is there a reason to use memset right before strcpy?

```
switch(argc)
{
    case 1  :
        printf("\nCommand: %s \n",argv[0]);
       break;
    case 2  :
        memset(program_input_string,0,sizeof(program_input_string));
        strcpy(program_input_string,argv[1]);
        printf("\nCommand: %s [%s] \n",argv[0],argv[1]);
       break;
    default :
        printf("\nCommand: %s \n",argv[0]);
}
```

Comment: You have to ask the original programmer about the reason behind it because it's not really needed.

Comment: It’s somewhat redundant but it does mean that the unused bytes after the string are all set to 0, which can be useful when debugging and for various other obscure things.

Comment: `strcpy(program_input_string,argv[1]);` is a **real** problem, though.  There's no protection from any buffer overflow.

Comment: You are not showing where `program_input_string` is used later – even the `printf`s use the original `argv` directly. That is, in the code shown not only is the `memset` unnecessary, but the `strcpy` as well, so it's not really possible to know why it might later be important for the tail of `program_input_string` to be zeroed, e.g., is it treated as something other than a string or passed to some external program where we don't want to leak data.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, this is on my list of issues to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering why memset was used in this particular case, where the next line of code stores the value in the variable that was just set to all 0 by memset. Is there a reason to use memset right before strcpy?

The particular `memset()` call presented sets *every byte* of the destination array to 0.  The `strcpy()` call, when successful, overwrites only as many bytes as are in the `argv[1]` string, including the terminator, which may be fewer.  Whether this distinction is in fact important to the program is impossible to determine from the code presented.

Note also that the code presented is subject to buffer overrun -- it is in fact an example of one of the canonical cases for that issue.  If `argv[1]` is *longer* than the destination array then undefined behavior ensues.

Answer (score 3):

The truth is there is *zero* reason to use `memset` + `strcpy` in this case. In fact if the programmer wanted to ensure that the remaining bytes were zeroed, then `strncpy` with a conditional for testing if the string fit in entirety into the buffer  should have been used:

```
strncpy(program_input_string, argv[1], sizeof program_input_string);

// if the last character in the array is not '\0', it means that the
// string did not fit into the array in its entirety, and perhaps 
// the only sensible course of action is to abort the program...
if (program_input_string[sizeof program_input_string - 1] != '\0') {
    fputs("The argument was too long!", stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

This has *two* obvious advantages: it does not set the initial sequence to zero needlessly *and* it cannot overrun the input buffer - and if the buffer overrun were to happen it will exit with a sensible error message and exit code.

---

Thus the definite answer to the question "why was this construct used" would be the all-too-common "programmer incompetence".

Answer (score 2):

It's *probably* unnecessary, but you should check carefully before you delete it.

The `memset()` ensures that any bytes after the terminal `\0` are zeroed out. If `program_input_string` is always read as a string and code always stops when it hits `\0` then what comes after doesn't matter.

It could be useful if there's code that reads from the entire buffer, trailing bytes included. For example, if all `sizeof(program_input_string)` bytes were copied into a network packet and sent over the wire you wouldn't want to transmit uninitialized bytes. In that case, zeroing out the buffer would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the call of memset is redundant. You may just write

```
strcpy(program_input_string,argv[1]);
```

because the function strcpy copies also the terminating zero in the destination string.

As an idea sometimes a character array need to contain several strings. In this case two consequitive zeroes mean the end of the set of strings stored in the character array. So it is required to initialize the array with zeroes.

Let's assume that the array `program_input_string` already contains strings

```
ABC\0DEF\0\0
```

then if to copy string E you will get

```
E\0C\0DEF\0\0
```

As it is seen the result is not what was expected. Now the array contains a set of three strings instead of one string.